# How to clean (disinfect) my dog everyday after walk?

Tags: dogs, grooming, diseases, cleaning, infections

To give you some perspective, my dog and I go for a walk, every morning (~ 45 min) and evening (~ 30 min).

We don't have any grounds nearby (only fields <sup>**(1)**</sup>) which means I have to walk him on streets with shrubs and small plans along the sides. There are a number of stray dogs and many people walk their dogs along the same route too. What this means is that there's fresh urine on almost every other plant <sup>**(2)**</sup> and mine inevitably ends up with urine all over his body <sup>**(3)**</sup>.

As you may know many dangerous diseases, e.g. Ebola, are introduced into the human population through close contact with the blood, secretions, organs or other bodily fluids of infected animals. This means that not only my dog, but also my entire family, especially me <sup>**(4)**</sup>, could be in danger.

I have no idea how to clean him up after everyday walks without damaging/harming his coat and skin. Shampooing is not an option as it results in dry skin. (Bathing him with just water doesn't disinfect him. Will a towel bath with Dettol be good enough? Will it introduce any side effects? I don't know.)

So, what should I do? How do you do it?

---

**Footnotes:**

1. And I don't walk him in fields due to fear of snakes.
2. Intact males and females which means they spray urine everywhere.
3. My dog wants to pee on the same spot, and doesn't get it over with by simply raising his leg. He first puts his head into the plant for inspection, and them moves around, inside and out, before he finishes the job he so diligently performs every single time.

   It's his only play time and he loves it the most. So I simply cannot be too restrictive, and even though I watch out for pee on plans, I inevitably miss one or he's too quick.
4. I kiss him, pet him and play with him; and I want to be able to without fear of contracting a disease.

Comment: In short you don't, if all the terrible diseases were that easy to catch, you and all of us would have been dead long ago.

Comment: You are in luck ..There are no diseases that are transmitted from dog to human through dog urine.

Comment: @Beth-loudninja-Whitezel that's not true - Leptospirosis is transmitted to humans from dog (or other animal) urine http://www.cdc.gov/leptospirosis/infection/index.html

Comment: @its_me I would use all this clean-disinfect-worry-repeat time to walk him a little longer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy wet wipes for dogs (and cats).

[image: Dog Deodorizer]
([Source](http://www.petsmart.com/dog/grooming-supplies/top-paw-super-deodorizing-dog-wipes-zid36-12657/cat-36-catid-100016;pgid=cBhgEzDhVABSRp06d1RxA1NF0000sPQ_jZVx;sid=08UTEHT3KdtAECDJCpdRFET9lrlEApf8j2NnhDl4?var_id=36-12657&_t=pfm%3Dcategory))

WIth these you could spot-clean your dog rather than giving him an entire bath.

I don't think it should have the same kind of problem as shampoo where it dries out the skin, because you're basically using a paper towel with some water and disinfectant, but I've only ever used them occasionally. So you might have to keep an eye on it if you're using it in the same spot day after day.

They also make wipes that are specifically for cleaning around the eyes and in the ears, so if your concern is with cleaning around his face I would suggest those.

But honestly though, the solution I would go with, is a simple washcloth with some soapy water. Use whatever dog approved soap/shampoo you would normally use, and however much you think you need to get his fur clean. That should be just as effective as any of the wipes, and more importantly cheaper. You can easily grab one as soon as you return, or have a small bucket and washcloth ready by the door for when you get back.

Comment: Would these be both safe for and friendly to a dog's (sensitive) nose?

Comment: @CGCampbell You mean like does it smell strongly of disinfectant? Or is it safe to use it on/around a dog's nose?

Comment: The ones I had didn't have any scent that I noticed. I don't know how safe it is to use around the nose, I'd have to find the label to check. But they do make special wipes specifically for cleaning around the eyes and in ears, so since those are made for sensitive areas, they might be better to use around the nose too.

Comment: @MattS. You suggest using "soapy water". What exactly do you mean by that? Dog Shampoo + Water (1 in 8)?

Comment: @its_me Yeah sorry, whatever dog approved soap/shampoo you would normally use for baths.

Comment: They're most likely just dampened with alcohol, which is the main ingredient in many hand sanitizers.

Answer (score 2):

I've used a white vinegar and water solution to wipe my dog's paws and underbelly. It disinfects and deters fleas/ticks that may have come aboard. The solution is one part vinegar to four parts water. I soak a towel and wipe my dog after coming home from a walk.

Answer (score 0):

Wet wipes won't do the trick to remove diesases, etc, whcih have been proven to be brought in. I put llittle booties on my dogs feet now..~~I've upgraded the cleaning:)
I have a bottle with a light mixture of Dawn soap and hibiclens~~Expensive but watered down is fine~ hospital grade antiseptic.
I dunk the cloth in the water and wash her face, legs, belly and area where she's peed, etc,. She is wearing jacket, so nothing on the body.

After I use the cloth, even though it's quite watered down, I use one that is water only to get off any soap. She's light so with a heavy rain, I might pop her in the tub and rinse her off, or give her a bath, depending on when last given. She is the cleanest dog around!